# Is there any difference between "from the beginning" and "in the beginning"?

Tags: phrases, differences, idioms

I am not sure if this is correct.

I feel that ***from the beginning*** implies something that lasts until now, while ***in the beginning*** implies something that only existed at the beginning. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  (Oh!  You wanted to know what it might be?)  "In the beginning" is about precisely that -- the beginning.  "From the beginning" implies a chronology from the beginning through to some later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is correct.

Except that "*from the beginning*" is not necessarily "until now." It could just mean from the beginning until a stated end, like:

"from the beginning of the Roman empire **until** the end of the Roman empire..."

But yes, "*in the beginning*" is **a point in time**, (a.k.a. the beginning).

"*From the beginning*" is a **period of time** (though not necessarily until now), determined by the use of *until (stated end)*.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, OP is correct. "From the beginning" implies something which lasts until now, while "in the beginning" implies something which existed in the beginning only.

Let me supplement this with an example:

1. **From the beginning,** we **have** a three-tier political system.
2. **In the beginning,** we **had** a two-tier political system.

Hope the issue is clear now.

Comment: Correction: *From the beginning we **have had** a three-tier political system.*

Comment: thank you, Dinesh Kumar Garg,  your supplement is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To me, "In the beginning" indicates a single point in time, whereas "From the beginning" inticates something on-going.  God's creation, therefore, may be viewed either way - a one-time event or an un-ending event. Do the words in Latin, Greek. Hebrew, (or an earlier language), indicate which phrase is the more intended?